# Вывод картинки с сохранением пропорций

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот таким не хитрым кодом вывожу изображение на странице:

```
var resultImg = document.getElementById('resultImg');
resultImg.setAttribute('src', canvasOriginal.toDataURL("image/png"));   
.....
<img id="resultImg" src="" style="max-width: 800px; max-height: 600px;"/>
```

Картинка может быть квадратной, прямоугольной или же тонкой и/или длинной. Выводить ее нужно в пределах 800 на 600. Как такое можно реализовать? На форуме находил вариант, но там берется div и в него картинка загружается как задний фон. Можно ли сделать по другому? 
P.S.: Если картинка маленькая она остается маленькой, если картинка большая(больше 800 на 600), то она должна уменьшится сохраняя пропорции, чтобы поместиться в эту область

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с квадратной картинкой. Сама картинка 800x800

```css
.img-block{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
 }
 .img-block>img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 0 0;}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
   <img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/082cf32e5a8846ae89628b2780595cf1.jpg">
</div>
```

Так же можно и с широкими и узкими картинками, картинка заполнит пространство внутри div пропорционально как вы и хотите

С учётом пожеланий в комментариях:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-block');
for (let i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
  divs[i].querySelector('img').height>divs[i].querySelector('img').width?divs[i].querySelector('img').style.height='100%':divs[i].querySelector('img').style.width='100%';
}
```

```css
.img-block{
width:800px;
height:600px;
border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wNsLqwP/1111.png">
</div>

<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://wallpapershome.ru/images/pages/pic_v/21485.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: не работает с длинными картинками, вот с такой например https://i.ibb.co/wNsLqwP/1111.png

Comment: @helldrg почему не работает? Она полностью вписалась по высоте в блок при этом сохранив пропорции. т.е. высота её стала 600px вместо 1000px исходника.
Соответственно ширина стала 2400px, то что влезло отобразилось, остальное вне блока невидимо, так как блок шириной 800px, вот вы и получили свои желаемые 800x600px

Comment: надо что бы картинка уменьшилась и влезла в область 800 на 600 сохранив пропорции

Comment: @helldrg Так это же ещё проще. Сейчас подредактирую ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Идеально =)